# Pageable REST API

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, pagination

I'm using Pageable to return json results with pages. One example of my controller

```
@GetMapping("/nome/{nome}")
public ResponseEntity<Page<Cidadao>> consultaPorNome(
        @PathVariable(value="nome",required=true) String nome,
        @RequestParam(value="pagina", defaultValue="0") Integer page,
        @RequestParam(value="quantidade", defaultValue="10") Integer linesPerPage,
        @RequestParam(value="ordem", defaultValue="nome") String orderBy, 
        @RequestParam(value="direcao", defaultValue="ASC") String direction){

    Page<Cidadao> lista = cidadaoService.findByNome(nome,page,linesPerPage,orderBy, direction);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(lista);


}
```

And i get json like

```
{
"content": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lucas"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Erick"
    },
],
"totalElements": 23,
"totalPages": 3,
"last": false,
"numberOfElements": 10,
"first": true,
"sort": [
    {
        "direction": "ASC",
        "property": "nome",
        "ignoreCase": false,
        "nullHandling": "NATIVE",
        "ascending": true,
        "descending": false
    }
],
"size": 10,
"number": 0
```

}

but i would like to return this way

```
{
    "data":{
         "content" : [
            {
             "id": 1,
              "name": "Lucas"
            },
            {
             "id": 1,
              "name": "Lucas"
            }         
          ],
          "totalElements": 23,
          "totalPages": 3,
          "last": false,
          "numberOfElements": 10,
          "first": true,
          "sort": [
              {
                  "direction": "ASC",
                  "property": "nome",
                  "ignoreCase": false,
                  "nullHandling": "NATIVE",
                  "ascending": true,
                  "descending": false
              }
          ],
          "size": 10,
          "number": 0
    },
    errors:[]
}
```

It is possible implements anything like this to change or add attributes like errors ? Or if possible change the name attributes from Page like totalElements for numberofTotalElementBySomething.... ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was looking for, I didn't find a beautiful solution to do this. So, I did this way:

Create a class called PageAdapter (or whatever you like)

```
public class PageAdapter<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable   {

    private long totalElements;
    private long totalPages;
    private long size;
    private List<T> content;

    public PageAdapter(Page<T> page){
        this.totalElements = page.getTotalElements();
        this.totalPages = page.getTotalPages();
        this.size = page.getSize();
        this.content = page.getContent();
    }
}
```

And receive within constructor the original Pageable.
You can customize your properties, these properties were used in my case.
After this, you can return the `PageAdapter` in your controller/resource.

if there is a better solution, I would like to know too.

A suggestion for you, spring can receive an instance of Pageable, so, you don't need to receive each parameter for size, page, order and etc.
Just do this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<Cidadao>> consultaPorNome(
    @PathVariable(value="nome",required=true) String nome, Pageable pageable){
```

You will have all information about size, page, order...

I'm not a native English speaker, so, may contains grammar errors.

Comment: I have a service return Page<Car> for example, so in my controller have i to use
public ResponseEntity <Page<PageAdapter>> search(parameters){
  PageAdapter page = new PageAdapter(Service);
return page?
}

Comment: What do you have to use? Pageable?

Comment: No meu controller de antes eu estava retornando um ResponseEntity<Page<minhaClasse>> isso me retornava minha pagina com os parametros de paginação. So que eu quero mudar o nome de algumas variaveis e adicionar um vetor de errors caso nao encontre nada por exemplo.

Comment: Você pode facilmente personalizar o PageAdapter. Basta que no controller você instancie `PageAdapter`, passando por parametro o `Page` que resultou do seu service.

Comment: Apesar de ter aparecido alguns warnings no controler justamente na declaração passando meu Page dentro do adapter , funcionou ! Valeu ,salvou meu dia passei o dia todo pesquisando isso kkk.

Comment: Vai aparecer warnings por causa do tipo do `PageAdapter`, que não é checado. Mas isso você pode ignorar. Caso tenha te ajudado, por favor, coloque como respondido, ao lado da minha resposta.

Comment: Blz, fiz isso ! valeu